# Indistinguishability processes vs finite dimensional distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have been wondering about two concepts of "sameness" of two stochastic processes. Suppose that both stochastic processes $X= \{X(t), t \ge 0 \}$ and $Y= \{Y(t), t \ge 0 \}$ are defined on same probability space.

We say that $X$ and $Y$ Indistinguishable if $P(X(t)=Y(t), \forall t \ge 0) = 1.$
I know that Indistinguishability imples that they have same finite dimensional distributions.

My questions:

- Does the other implication also hold under some assumptions? For example for continuous processes?
- If I have two wienner processes $W_1$ and $W_2$ on same probability space, are they indistinguishable?

Answer (score 5):

Let $W_1$ be a Wiener process and define $W_2(t):= -W_1(t)$. Then $W_2$ is again a Wiener process on the same space, but the two are certainly **not** indistinguishable! Note that $W_2$ also has the same finite-dimensional distributions as $W_1$.

Answer (score 3):

The natural notion that is weaker than indistinguishability is one process being a modification of the other. This means that the two processes agree a.s. at any finite set of deterministic times. As a consequence they also agree a.s. at any countable set of deterministic times. Thus if they enjoy some pathwise regularity such as continuity or the cadlag property then they will also be indistinguishable.

Merely having the same finite dimensional distributions is a total non-starter; consider even just the case where the time set is a single point (so you just have one random variable) to see why.

Comment: Dear Ian, could you explain or give a reference on why if two process have the same finite dimensional distributions then they agree on a countable set of deterministic times as well? Thank you

Comment: @Sarah It is just $P \left ( \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{  \omega : X_{t_i}=Y_{t_i} \} \right )=1 \: \forall n \Rightarrow P \left ( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{ \omega : X_{t_i}=Y_{t_i} \} \right )=1$ from continuity of measure.

Comment: Oh... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sarah Sorry, to be clear, what I aid is that if two processes are equal a.s. at any finite set of deterministic times, then they are also equal a.s. at any countable set of deterministic times. Having the same finite dimensional distributions is much weaker than these hypotheses.

Comment: Dear Ian, if two processes are equal a.s. at any finite set of deterministic sets then they have the same finite dimensional distributions, or not?

Comment: I mean, why aren't they equivalent?

Comment: @Sarah Equal a.s. at any finite set of deterministic times is much *stronger* than just equal finite dimensional distributions. Loosely speaking this is analogous to comparing "equal a.s." vs. "have the same distribution" with random variables (I say "loosely speaking" because with continuous time stochastic processes there are two different kinds of "equal a.s.", namely "modification" and "indistinguishable").

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. But can we perhaps say that if two process have the same finite dimensional distributions then they have the same countably dimensional distributions? Maybe using continuity of the measure as well (?)

Comment: @Sarah The countable dimensional distribution doesn't actually make much sense in most contexts. Typical countable events that you would want to measure, like say $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty W_i \in [a_i,b_i])$ for a Wiener process $W_i$, end up having probability zero. The actual way this extension works is a bit more subtle, but thankfully the Kolmogorov extension theorem takes care of it for us with essentially no hypotheses.

Comment: Dear @Ian I could get back to the problem again. I would like to ask you: I have two processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$. $Y_t$ was obtained using precisely Kolmogorov's theorem out of the probability measures on $X_t$. $X_t$ has continuous paths, and I would like to infer (for a countbale deterministic set of times) that $Y_t$ has continuous paths at these times as well. Is this possible? Or does it even make sense? Thank you :)

Comment: @Sarah If you took a modification rather than considering indistinguishable processes then no, that is impossible to guarantee. Paths of a a modification of a process which has continuous paths can fail to be continuous always, as long as the point of discontinuity has probability zero to be anywhere in particular.